Cannot resolve .less absolute paths in vite
I am migrating from craco to vite and currently have issues with .less files:

import @import '~antd/dist/antd.less'; doesnt work with following error:

Pre-transform error: [less] '~antd/dist/antd.less' wasn't found. Tried - C:\...\ais-front\src\shared\styles\~antd\dist\antd.less,node_modules\~antd\dist\antd.less
while i set alias for this in vite.config { find: "~", replacement: "" }

Vite doesnt recognize absolute paths in .less files

@import "shared/styles/colors.less"; gives
Pre-transform error: [less] 'shared/styles/colors' wasn't found. Tried - C:\...\src\components\header\shared\styles\colors.less
From C:\...\ais-front\src\components\header\shared\styles\colors.less, looks like path shared/styles/colors.less just adds to file from it was imported

Vite cannot recognize absolute paths on .less files without adding src infront, is tsx files it works fine




Can you help me with resolving this issues?
My vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
      react(),
      tsconfigPaths(),
  ],
  css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
          less: {
              math: "always",
              javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
      },
  },
  resolve: {
       alias: [
           { find: "~", replacement: "" },
       ],
  },
})

tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",

    /* Extended from main project */
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

